# C# PowerPoint convert file with embedded media

Tags: video, ms-office, powerpoint, office-pia

I need to convert a powerpoint file to the latest powerpoint version in my case pptx 2010.
so a ppt file 97-2000 or pptx 2007 should be converted to pptx 2010.
the special ability of 2010 is that all media objects (sound/video) can be included in the inner zip file and have not to be in the same folder anymore.

The method Convert2 always throws an error no matter what powerpoint file i take.
EnsureAllMediaUpgraded doesn't work neither.
SaveAs converts the file format but does not embed media objects.

The only way i know is to remove a video shape and use the add video method, but in this case all effects and animations are lost... so that is a nonsatisfying way.

there must be a way to do programmatically what i can do in the gui of powerpoint 2010.
Backstore > Upgrade

Has anyone a solution or idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use http://www.aspose.com/ 
I think it can help you.